# What are the prerequisites for changing government in Europa Universalis IV?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am currently playing a game as the Iroquois Nation, and I have:

1. Completed all native ideas
2. Have a number of provinces bordering a westernized nation (France to the North)
3. I have the Conquest of Paradise DLC installed and active.
4. (Possibly Irrelevant) I am independently at level 6 administrative tech.

As you can see in the screenshot below, despite the above I still cannot change my government type.  Does anyone know why or what the complete list of requirements is to change government types as a North American nation?

[image: Bordered by france and can't change governments]
<sup>*Click image for larger version.*</sup>

**UPDATE**: @CrusaderJ posited a very reasonable explanation that perhaps the French provinces were not cores, but sadly that is not the case as you can see in this here:

[image: French-Canadian Core]
<sup>*Click image for larger version.*</sup>

AND if that weren't enough, it appears that I'm bordered on the east by the Netherlands, also western, also touching a core province.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ack, finally found it by thrashing.  Maybe some of you guys already knew this, but I did not... As it turns out, EU IV provides a different, entirely separate way of changing your government type to Western for the first time.  It's on the new Native Ideas page all the way at the bottom after completing all of the native ideas, a new button stating, "Reform Government" - Once you press that your government reforms.

It also looks like @Nix was correct both in noting that the nation to the North was actually French-Canada, a colonial nation, and that this fact did not matter.  Once I finally found the correct button I went back and replayed the game from an earlier point where I was only connected to French Canada, and not the Netherlands, and I was still given the option to Reform Government.

[image: Location of Reform Government Button]
<sup>*Click image for larger version.*</sup>

Comment: As a note for people playing newer version of EUIV, the location of the "Natives" tab has now changed to a pop up button in the lower right hand side of the screen, similar to the pop up for Holy Roman Empire.

Answer (score 4):

This is a restriction on the tribal nations. If you have the DLC, you will eventually be able to reform your government – but not untill you are exposed to western countries. From what I can understand from your question, you already fulfill all requirements (point 1-3).

Your tech level shouldn't matter untill you decide to westernize – but in order to that, you must have reformed your government. Ergo is your point 4 irrelevant, as fas as I can tell.

> **Requirements**
>   - All native ideas filled.
>   - A core province next to a Western nation's core province.
>   **Effects**
>   - All native ideas lost.
>   - All native buildings are lost (also the already built ones are lost), the standard building interface replaces it.
>   - Tech level advances to 90% of the Western nation's, rounded down.(?)
>   - Government changes to the form of government that borders the nation, if you border a kingdom then you will reform into a kingdom, same for republics and theocracies.
>   - Allows westernizing the country, if the regular conditions are met (at least 8 technologies behind the western neighbour)

[See more on the EU4 Wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Tribal_nation#Requirements).

Comment: Perhaps the French provinces are not core provinces?

Comment: @CrusaderJ OP wrote in a comment (since deleted for some reason) that they are cored, but he would check. I think he's right, as those should be colonized provinces, which are always cored (as opposed to conquered provinces). I also think that's a colonial nation (notice it has a capital), but that shouldn't matter ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did indeed comment and then remove that.  I thought it might be simpler to check before commenting.  My (Iroquois) provinces are definitely cored, but I can't say for sure that the French provinces are cored.  That would seem to be the only possible solution left (outside of a bug).  So I will check that as soon as I am able and let you guys know - thanks so much for the ideas!

Comment: @Palantar That's cool. Sorry for "calling you out", but I thought it was relevant, in case CrusaderJ had an alternative solution. :)